# CUDA Unable to see shared memory values in Nsight debugging

Tags: debugging, cuda, nsight, gpu-shared-memory

I've been struggling for some time a problem I can't seem to find a solution to.

The problem is that when I try to debug my CUDA code using Nvidia Nsight under Visual Studio 2008 I get strange results when using shared memory.

My code is:

```
template<typename T>
__device__
T integrate()
{
   extern __shared__ T s_test[]; // Dynamically allocated shared memory
   /**** Breakpoint (1) here ****/
   int index = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x; // Local index in block. Column major ordering
   if(index < 64 && blockIdx.x==0) { // Only work on a few values. Just testing
      s_test[index] = (T)index;
      /* Some other irelevant code here */
   }
   return v;
}
```

When I reach `Breakpoint (1)` and inspect the shared memory inside Visual Studio Watch window only the first 8 values of the array change and the others remain null. I would expect all first 64 to do so.
[image: Watch window from Visual Studio]

I thought it might have something to do with all warps not executing simultaneously. So I tried synchronizing them. I added this code inside `integrate()`

```
template<typename T>
__device__
T integrate()
{
   /* Old code is still here */

   __syncthreads();
   /**** Breakpoint (2) here ****/
   if(index < 64 && blockIdx.x==0) {
      T tmp = s_test[index]; // Write to tmp variable so I can inspect it inside Nsight Watch window
      v = tmp + index; // Use `tmp` and `index` somehow so that the compiler doesn't optimize it out of existence
   }
return v;
}
```

But the problem is still there. Furthermore the rest of the values inside `tmp` are not `0` as the Watch window from VS is indicating.
[image: Watch window from Nsight]

I must mention that it takes a lot of steps to step over `__syncthreads()`, so when I reach it I just jump to `Breakpoint (2)`. What is going on?

---

**EDIT** Information about the system/launch configuration

**System**

- Name Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7300  @ 2.66GHz
- Architecture x86
- Frequency    2.666 MHz
- Number of Cores  2
- Page Size    4.096
- Total Physical Memory    3.582,00 MB
- Available Physical Memory    1.983,00 MB
- Version Name Windows 7 Ultimate
- Version Number   6.1.7600

**Device** GeForce 9500 GT

- Driver Version   301.42
- Driver Model WDDM
- CUDA Device Index    0
- GPU Family   G96
- Compute Capability   1.1
- Number of SMs    4
- Frame Buffer Physical Size (MB)  512
- Frame Buffer Bandwidth (GB/s)    16
- Frame Buffer Bus Width (bits)    128
- Frame Buffer Location    Dedicated
- Graphics Clock (Mhz) 812
- Memory Clock (Mhz)   500
- Processor Clock (Mhz)    1625
- RAM Type DDR2

**IDE**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008
- NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition, Version 2.2 Build No. 2.2.0.12255

**Compiler** comands

```
1> "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\\bin\nvcc.exe"  -G  -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\"   --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" -D_NEXUS_DEBUG -g  -D_DEBUG -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -I"inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\\include" -maxrregcount=0  --compile -o "Debug/process_f2f.cu.obj" process_f2f.cu
```

**Launch configuration**. The shared memory size and doesn't seem to matter. I've tried several versions. The one I've worked with the most is:

- Shared memory 2048 Bytes
- Grid/block sizes : {101, 101, 1} , {16, 16, 1}

Comment: Can you provide device info, nsight version, driver version, launch dimensions, and dynamic shared memory size? If you provide a full reproducible including compiler switches then the team can look into the issue.

Comment: I've added all the information. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Iam, I am unable to repro this issue. Would you mind getting into contact with me? You may email me at devtools-support at nvidia dot com. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem couldn't be reproduced and seems to have turned into an off Stack Overflow bug report with a vendor

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting `__syncthreads()` after assigning the values?

```
template<typename T>
__device__
T integrate()
{
   extern __shared__ T s_test[]; // Dynamically allocated shared memory
   int index = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x; // Local index in block. Column major ordering
   if(index < 64 && blockIdx.x==0) { // Only work on a few values. Just testing
      s_test[index] = (T)index;
      /* Some other irelevant code here */
   }
   __syncthreads();
   /**** Breakpoint (1) here ****/
   return v;
}
```

And try to see the values at this breakpoint.